# using a class as a variable identifier?

Tags: java, class, methods, instance-variables, class-variables

I am making a couple of simple classes to calculate a few things in a monopoly game.

My first class (BoardSquare) has methods to get and set the playerid squarename and the number of houses on the square while I have another method calculating the rent based on how many houses are on the square with an if-statement.

My second class (House) has a method that gets how much a new house costs for the property in another if statement and then has a set method to set the house price.

My goal is to use the House class inside of the boardsquare class. What I mean is that instead of having an instance variable

```
    int houses;
```

to hold the number of houses on a square I use a variable of type House. In other words, rather than having a number of houses on a square you have either 0 or 1 Houses.

I know what I want to do I just don't know how to do it.

So I have an instance variable 
        House houses;
and my getHouses method reads

```
    public House getHouses(this is where i had int h(from the constructor) but I dont know what to put here now)
    {
    Whatever I need to put here to access the class House
    }
```

Hopefully you can understand what I am trying to accomplish. I would be grateful for any tip you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `Collection<House>`.

Do not use `LinkedList<House>` unless you need specific behavior of a linked list.  This also goes for `ArrayList`.  You may want either of these as an implementation, but use the most abstract collection you can.

- `List` is the order of the houses is important
- `Set` if you want to enforce only one instance of each type of house (may not apply)

So:

```
Collection<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();

public Collection<House> getHouses() {
    return houses;
}

public void addHouse(House newHouse) {
    houses.add(newHouse);
}
```

I've chosen an `ArrayList` implementation because it is efficient to add new elements to the end of the list.  This is also true of `LinkedList`, but `LinkedList` adds additional overhead that makes it efficient to insert entries into the `List`.  See the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Add an instance variable within the BoardSquare class as follows:

```
LinkedList<House> houses;
```

If there can only be 0 or 1 houses you can have an instance variable of type House, and an instance variable of type boolean called hasHouses.

Comment: I always like to avoid showing implementation in my class's fields.  i.e.) Just use a generic List<House> as opposed to LinkedList<House> so when working with this field anywhere else in the future, you can use whatever list you'd like.

Comment: that can work too.  It's LinkedList because I'm assuming this is a variable length object.